# how can i removeChild?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have problem with removeChild in XML button menu
im calling button temp from library with Linkage
here is my code where i write it

```
        var genButton:butonProba;

    var i:uint = 0;

    for each (var page:XML in generacijeXML.gener.generation) {

        genButton = new butonTest();    

        genButton.butonText.text = page.@name;

        genButton.source = page.source.toString();

        genButton.butonText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

        genButton.x = 16 + i*225;
        genButton.y = -30;

        genButton.buttonMode = true;
        genButton.mouseChildren = false;

        addChild(genButton);

        i++;
}
```

and everything is normal.....

now when i want to make 1 more button when i click on it i want to remove all xml buttons which i call before

im trying simple like this

```
close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closed);

  function closed(event:Event):void {
  genButton.removeChild(0);
}
```

and this

```
close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closed);

  function closed(event:Event):void {
  removeChild(genButton);
}
```

but dont work
does any1 have idea how can i do that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add all buttons in one container. Create the container as an instance member and add it to the stage in the constructor or your init method:

```
 public var buttonContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
 addChild(buttonContainer);
```

In your loop add all the created buttons to this container:

```
 ...
 genButton.buttonMode = true;
 genButton.mouseChildren = false;

 buttonContainer.addChild(genButton);

 i++;
```

in you click handler remove all children from the container:

```
 close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closed);

 function closed(event:Event):void {
     while(buttonContainer.numChildren > 0 )
     {
          buttonContainer.removeChildAt(0);
     }
 }
```

hope that helped

Comment: "I would add all buttons in one container. Create the container as an instance member and add it to the stage in the constructor or your init method:" i dont know how to do that but im done like this var buttonContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(buttonContainer); without public and it works fine. Thanks alot